# Sun X4150 not powering up via power button

Tags: ubuntu, troubleshooting, sun

## What I have

I have a Sun Server X4150 ( https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19121-01/sf.x4150/820-1852-13/doradi-overview.html ) which I have set up in a research environment (I'm testing various OSs and RAID types).

Currently I have Ubuntu installed on it (not that I think that's related, I don't). I have had various distros installed from various packages (including but not limited to: ubuntu desktop and server versions (various), FreeBSD (via FreeNAS), OpenIndiana, Rockstor, and various Live CDs).

The system is in standby mode which is indicated by the single flash of the green power led about every 2 seconds.

I have power going to both power supplies and the PSU fans are hheard to be running, and their indicator light on the back indicates `OK`.

There are no `Alert` LEDs illuminated front or back.

I can log in via IPMI and issue a `on`, `off` or `soft` command to bring the system up or down and this is my usual way of doing it as I operate the unit remotely. However, I have one workstation set up close to the unit and I am also able to reach across and just power it up by physically pressing the power button on the front of the unit.

Some units have a recessed button that you need to use a pin, paper clip, pen or other pointed object to press it; others have a physical exposed power button you can press with your finger. Mine has the exposed button. (again, not that this would make any difference).

## The problem

**The power button on the front no longer works.**

## When the problem appeared

I'm not too certain on this, it has been like it for a few weeks now, but as far as I can remember, it was functional when this current OS was first installed and had been used a number of times since.

## What I've tried

- totally removing power from the unit, letting it cool down and re-applying power
- searched `BIOS` for a setting I may have inadvertently changed (nothing pops up at me)
- tried powering down the system different ways (ie let it start up and powered down via system controls, via command line, via IPMI `power off` and via IPMI `power soft`.
- I have removed each of the power supplies and reseated them to ensure they are HOME.

None of these allowed the power button to restart the system, whereas it use to function before.

The power button also would perform a graceful shutdown if tapped for a moment, or a forced shutdown if held for a longer period of time. Neither functionality on the shutdown, nor basic functionality of startup occur at all when using the button. It appears as physically bad.

## Google

There are a couple of references on Google where this appears to be a common-ish problem, but no solution has yet been recorded. One such record from reddit appears here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/1700vq/anybody_know_sun_hardware_x86_based_well_i_have_a/

## Others

A friend of mine has the same unit which he has had for a number of years. He wasn't even aware of the power button on the front of the unit and habitually forcibly removed power if he needed to, but usually shutdown via `SSH`. Now that he knows about the power button, he uses it as well. His is currently still working, whereas mine is not.

#### Other Notes:

- One thing to note which I thought was/is a little odd, then after having the system powered off and reconnecting power, the system is in `standby` mode automatically (flashing green power led on the front). I would have thought that at least initially it would be in a pure power off state until it was at least first powered.
- Given this is an R&D unit, it doesn't generally remain powered on, although it can be on for a number of days.
- Whilst NOW it is only started via IPMI, it was often powered up via the power button, and it was most usually shut down by the command line remotely via `SSH`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Tried to replace the actual button? if yes, then I forecast a motherboard problem coming. as it can easilly be some some component on the motherboard that are no longer working.

Comment: I haven't yet, and nor have I tried, mainly because it also provides another function. If held down simultaneously with the `location indicator` button in the same area, it puts the LEDs on the front panel into a test (ie all on) and requires the two buttons to be pressed again simultaneously to revert to normal operation. If you do this without the power button, (ie just operate the location indicator switch) then only that LED flashes. So I've determined the power button is in fact working.

Comment: I mentioned I did find someone else with the same problem, but forgot to mention that we are not alone. there are several reports from various sources that this is a problem, none of which have a solution (as yet), although I am determined to find one :)